# Рекурсивный конструктор

Tags: c++, ооп

класс TreeNode наследуется от CalcTree, в классе CalcTree создается указатель на TreeNode => вызывается конструктор TreeNode, который рекурсивно вызывает конструктор CalcTree. как от этого избавиться?

```
template <typename type_t>
CalcTree<type_t>::CalcTree()
{
    head_node (new TreeNode<type_t>(0));
    log_file = fopen(log_filename, "w");
}

TreeNode<type_t>::TreeNode(const type_t num = 0, int type_node_t = VALUE, TreeNode<type_t>* left_t = nullptr, TreeNode<type_t>* right_t = nullptr) :
            number(num),
            type_node(type_node_t),
            left_child(left_t),
            right_child(right_t)
        {}
```

Comment: Код приведите как вы это делаете.

Comment: Откуда же нам знать "как от этого избавиться"? У вашей рекурсии, как и любой другой рекурсии, где-то должно быть дно, по достижении которого рекурсия прекращается. Это у вас надо спрашивать, где дно у вашей рекурсии. А если вы не знаете, где оно, то зачем вы создавали такую рекурсию?

Comment: что к чему, при чем тут дно, мне не нужна рекурсия? мне нужно избежать повторного вызова конструктора CalcTree

Comment: чтобы не было так много вопросов, приведите объявление классов, а не определение конструкторов

Comment: "Не нужна рекурсия"? Так уберите ее. Почему у вас вообще `TreeNode` наследуется от `CalcTree`, если создание `CalcTree` требует создания нового `TreeNode`? Какая логика могла привести к такой бесконечно зацикленной структуре данных?

Comment: Я слабо знаком с наследованием. мне нужно чтобы переменная log_file была одинаковой для всех TreeNode

Answer (score 1):

Просто инициализируйте этот указатель нулем, а  в наследниках можете инициализировать  адресом  обьекта своего типа, по следующему образцу:

```
struct A;
struct B {
    A* pa;
    B() : pa(nullptr) {}
};
struct A : B{
    A() { pa = new A; }
};
```

Другое дело, что нет никакого смысла в этом. Этот указатель вполне можете хранить и в самом классе наследника. Базовому классу он вообше не нужен

Comment: Я в нем храню указатель на вершину дерева, поэтому нужен

Comment: Churkin Aleksey, не знаю ваши намерения, но базовый класс ничего не знает о наследниках, наследником может стать любой, кого вы назначите наследником. Как может базовый класс содержать адрес пока еще неизвестной сущности?  Он может содержать указатель  на свой экземпляр или своего базового класса.